# Preventing EMI on PCB

Tags: motor, pcb-design

i've made a project consisting of 3 DC motor pumps, Atmega328p on custom PCB, and a relay. I found a problem which causes my PCB custom arduino trips over and over again caused by 12V DC MOTOR. I fix it already by putting a flyback diode on motor. it runs much better but still have a small number of trips on my arduino.

[image]

probably i've a bad PCB design and lack of components.

is there a way to prevent these electromagnetic interference caused by motor? 
or some improvements on my PCB board?

Comment: Step one would be to add the missing decoupling capacitors to the MCU. Step two would be to use a proper ground pour instead of wimpy traces.

Comment: is there other way to put  the decoupling capacitors without making and design the new pcb? using this current PCB that i already make?

Comment: Use 0805 SMD capacitors and solder them between the MCU pins on the underside of the board.

Comment: Place the through-hole capacitors flat on the underside of the board. Bend the leads so they touch the solder joints of the IC(-holder). The solder them, and clip any excess lead.

Answer (score 0):

Had a problem like this. I ended up using a separate power supply for my DC motor. Don't forget to connect the GND's.

Comment: do you mean to connect GND motor and arduino in the same GND? because mine was using 12V DC pump while the arduino had their own power supply.

Comment: Yes, connect a GND between both

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you can try. First thing that comes to mind is hooking up the power source to an oscilloscope and see if there is not a big voltage dip when motor starts running/runs. This could happen if the motor attempts to draw more current than the power source can deliver, hence the voltage of source would drastically drop and Arduino would restart.

Second thing, assuming this is EMI, which I doubt - You need a proper ground plane, not just a thin trace. That would definitely help. Third thing would be reducing loop areas, by which I mean putting power and GND lines close to each other, look at http://www.ti.com/lit/an/szza009/szza009.pdf. This is a very resourceful document.

Third thing is - put a decoupling capacitor as close to the Arduino as possible. This will even out any spikes you may get, or any unexpected instability.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The most critical failing of your PCB is the fact that you have no decoupling capacitors near your MCU power pins. These are absolutely required, and are not optional.

To modify your existing PCB, so you don't have to roll a new one, just solder a 0.1µF 0805 SMD capacitor between each VCC and GND pair of pins on the underside of the board.

You should also reduce both the ground impedance and the power supply impedance by replacing your ground traces with a ground pour, and fatten your power traces up a little.

Comment: i don't have SMD components over here. any alternative? a ceramic or something?

Comment: You could solder a small leaded ceramic in the same way - just be careful of shorts. Insulate the leads if you can.

Comment: can i use ceramic 22uF? as this only on my inventory for now.

Comment: Ceramic 22uF? I think you have the wrong value there. If they're the ones that you use for the crystal then you probably mean pF not uF. And no. They're too small a value. You need around 100nF (0.1uF, 100000pF). They are the single most common value of ceramic capacitor in use in digital circuits. Get some. You will need them.